# Possible to run two ContentHandlers for a single parse in Apache-Tika?

Tags: java, tesseract, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika to parse documents and generate both a plaintext version and an HTML preview of the document. I'm able to generate both just fine if I call the `parse` function twice and pass in two separate ContentHandlers— this works great for text only documents. But when I get documents that require OCR with tesseract, it's a bit of a problem— it's extremely wasteful to call the `parse` function twice because it does the OCR (which can take a minute or so) twice as well.

I know I can write my own ContentHandler, but just wondering if anyone knows of an out-of-the-box solution for this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news - Apache Tika provides something out of the box for this!

[TeeContentHandler - Content handler proxy that forwards the received SAX events to zero or more underlying content handlers.](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/sax/TeeContentHandler.html)

Just create your 2+ real Content Handlers, pass those to the [constructor of TeeContentHandler](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/sax/TeeContentHandler.html#TeeContentHandler-org.xml.sax.ContentHandler...-), then hand the TeeContentHandler to Tika when you do the parse

Comment: Boom, there it is! Much appreciated.